# Find daily observation closest to specific time for irregularly spaced data

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have a python dataframe like

```
Out[110]:
Time
2014-09-19 21:59:14    55.975
2014-09-19 21:56:08    55.925
2014-09-19 21:53:05    55.950
2014-09-19 21:50:29    55.950
2014-09-19 21:50:03    55.925
2014-09-19 21:47:00    56.150
2014-09-19 21:53:57    56.225
2014-09-19 21:40:51    56.225
2014-09-19 21:37:50    56.300
2014-09-19 21:34:46    56.300
2014-09-19 21:31:41    56.350
2014-09-19 21:30:08    56.500
2014-09-19 21:28:39    56.375
2014-09-19 21:25:34    56.350
2014-09-19 21:22:32    56.400
2014-09-19 21:19:27    56.325
2014-09-19 21:16:25    56.325
2014-09-19 21:13:21    56.350
2014-09-19 21:10:18    56.425
2014-09-19 21:07:13    56.475
Name: Spread, dtype: float64
```

which extends over long time periods (months to years) so with very many observation for each day. What I want to do is that I for each day want to retrieve the time series observation closest to a specific time, say 16:00.

My approach so far have been

```
eodsearch = pd.DataFrame(df['Date'] + datetime.timedelta(hours=16))

eod = df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(eodsearch['Date'] ,method='nearest')]
```

which currently gives me an error of

```
"Cannot convert input [Time Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]] of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> to Timestamp
```

Moreover I saw that get_loc also accepted tolerance as an input so if I could set tolerance to say 30 min that would be great as well.

Any advice on why my code fails or how to fix it?

Comment: Please do not post data as images.  I have hand-typed your data and replaced the image and formatted your code as code.  See [Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to format code in your questions and answers.

Answer (score 5):

## Preparing data:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import Hour

df.sort_index(inplace=True)  # Sort indices of original DF if not in sorted order
# Create a lookup dataframe whose index is offsetted by 16 hours
d = pd.DataFrame(dict(Time=pd.unique(df.index.date) + Hour(16)))
```

(i): ***use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) which supports both ways lookup of observations:*** (both ways compatible)

```
# Find values in original within +/- 30 minute interval of lookup 
df.reindex(d['Time'], method='nearest', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('30Min'))
```

[image]

---

(ii) : ***use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) after identifying unique dates in the original `DF`***: (backward compatible)

```
# Find values in original within 30 minute interval of lookup (backwards)
pd.merge_asof(d, df.reset_index(), on='Time', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('30Min'))
```

[image]

---

(iii): ***To obtain dates ranging from `+/-` 30 minute bandwidth interval by querying and reindexing:***

`Index.get_loc` operates on a single label inputted, hence an entire series object cannot be passed directly to it.

Instead, [`DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time.html) which gives all rows that lie within the specified `start_time` & `end_time` of the indices day-wise would be more suitable for this purpose. (Both endpoints are inclusive)

---

```
# Tolerance of +/- 30 minutes from 16:00:00
df.iloc[df.index.indexer_between_time("15:30:00", "16:30:00")]
```

[image]

***Data used to arrive at the result:***

```
idx = pd.date_range('1/1/2017', periods=200, freq='20T', name='Time')
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(observation=np.random.uniform(50,60,200)), idx)
# Shuffle indices
df = df.sample(frac=1., random_state=42)
```

Info:

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 200 entries, 2017-01-02 07:40:00 to 2017-01-02 10:00:00
Data columns (total 1 columns):
observation    200 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 3.1 KB
```

Comment: After inspecting the output it seems that merge_asof only looks at the values before the specified timepoint so not +/- but rather only - ?

Comment: From  (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof) 

I found "For each row in the left DataFrame, we select the last row in the right DataFrame whose ‘on’ key is less than or equal to the left’s key. "

Comment: That seems to be the case however. It seems to be following `direction='backward'` at the moment. Starting with [`v  0.20.0`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof), you can provide `direction='nearest'` along with the set tolerance interval to achieve `+/-` bandwith of matching. Good observation by the way.

Comment: Added an alternative approach which hopefully gives `+/-` range of matches. Please check.

Comment: I took some time (really just begun coding in Python last week) but yes now it seems to work as expected, many thanks!